# Is it appropriate that my boss asks my teammate to validate my data work, and CC's me on the email instead of addressing it verbally?

Tags: management, work-experience

My supervisor requested that my teammate does a quick validation on my work. He didn't ask me to explain my logic or even talk to me verbally about my teammate and I validating it together. Instead, he sends an email, with the project sponsor CC'd to have the other analyst validate the numbers. It feels very disrespectful to me. I am not in training, and the project sponsor is not in a department the other analyst is familiar with; so I don't think he can develop a full picture.

Is this normal?

Comment: I doubt this is about the quality of your work, specifically, as much as standard, objective quality assurance review.

Comment: Since it is normal for some industries, and abnormal for others, it would help to have an idea of what kind of work you do.  Also, do you see it happening for others in your company?

Comment: Is your question about the request for validation or email vs verbal?

Comment: Are you a business/data analyst? Is the teammate just independently verifying the numbers? I would just talk to your manager and ask if this is standard procedure. As a software engineer, all of my code needs to be reviewed regardless of my seniority or tenure with the company. I would imagine an analyst that deals with numbers should have their numbers independently reviewed.

Answer (score 12):

This is called getting peer review.

It is very normal. I would never send anything to my boss without a peer review attached. This isn't about you being right or wrong, its about having more than one person look at it. Peer reviews are pretty much an industry standard.

Comment: Um, that does depend on the industry.  And we don't know if it is standard for the OP.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek care to supply an answer of your own?

Comment: @RichardU Why should they? They were suggesting an improvement to _your_ answer. As it stands, I agree with thursdaysgeek. This is certainly not standard in every industry.

Comment: @RichardU No, because I don't know yet whether this is a normal thing in her industry.  As a programmer/analyst, I rarely get peer or code reviews, although we do have testing by someone else.  Even that has varied with jobs.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek that very concerning. As a programmer I do peer reviews almost daily and have all of my stuff peer reviewed. The industry is irrelevant anything to with logic and number usually has a peer review process

Comment: @only_pro 1)This is not my answer 2) that was not an effort to improve the answer.

Answer (score 3):

That's pretty standard for the industry.  Code reviews are for making sure shop standards are maintained, and nobody needs your permission for verifying that your work is not damaging the company.

Your work does not belong to you, it belongs to the company and they do not have to appease you to ensure that everything is working properly any more than an automobile factory worker needs to be notified when they test the cars before they go out.

I've been coding for over 20 years and my code is verified by my peers.  If you cop an attitude over this, you'll find you've made a career limiting move.  You're not being disrespected, you're being held to an industry standard.

If you've never come across this before, then you're likely junior enough so that this should be a very regular thing.  It is not disrespect or punishment, it is what is to be expected, nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

Other have answered that this is a standard practice. But, evidently, it was not a standard practice for you, nor you have been notified whether that is the process.

For your own sanity, you deserve an explanation. Don't assume malice, but ask your manager something like:

> Hi, I wonder if that's standard practice of peer-review, or you think my work need check?

Also it might be useful to show that you can be proactive and willing to help your manager:

> Should I schedule these check myself in the future, so you don't have to waste your time on emails?

This way you'll do few things:

- hopefully get more comfortable, since now you will understand situation and process
- take initiative in your own hands, which is always appreciated
- get clearer picture of expectations. After all, maybe this is a process all new hires go through, and in 4 months you'll be on your own (i assume you are relatively new to the org)

As Joel Spolsky [wrote](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/10/controlling-your-environment-makes-you-happy/), people are happy when they control their environment. Get more control by clearing this out, not by blindly assuming that this is OK.